# Dealing with python 3 unicode output in powershell - can it be done cleanly?

Tags: python, powershell, unicode, utf-8

I've got a simple python script, `foo.py`, that outputs a unicode character:

```
import sys
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(b'\xe2\x96\x88'.decode('utf8'))
```

I want to run it in powershell and pipe the output to Write-Host:

```
PS> c:\python37\python.exe foo.py | Write-Host
```

If I do this, the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\pyen.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(b'\xe2\x96\x88'.decode('utf8'))
  File "C:\python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2588' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
cp1252
```

It turns out this isn't even a Write-Host problem. Just assigning the output to a variable, or piping it to Out-Null, give the same error:

```
PS> c:\python37\python.exe foo.py | Out-Null #Same error
PS> $a = c:\python37\python.exe foo.py #Same error
PS> c:\python37\python.exe foo.py #No error, stdout encoding is printed as utf-8
```

I've gone down the rabbit hole of why this is happening. Powershell picks the default windows codepage (cp1252) for many things.

This answer offers a couple solutions: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window)

Unfortunately, changing my `$PROFILE` to set the input and output encoding doesn't help.

The more permanent solution in that answer of enabling utf-8 systemwide **does fix this**, but that is a beta feature and can break other things, so I'd rather not go down that road.

I've also played with setting the python environment variable for encoding or modifying the python source, but these aren't great answers either, as that means tweaking or altering any python code whose output I want to pipe to Write-Host.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not seeing the point of Write-Host in your example, is there reason you want to use it?

Comment: Yeah. All of this is actually running in a powershell script that uses `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` to keep a log of what happened. The python code is actually invoked by an exe that is run from the powershell script, and without the Write-Host, the output, while it appears in the console, is not logged to the transcript.

Comment: I updated the question as this occurs in several other scenarios too -  basically doing almost anything with the output causes the same issue.

Comment: Check `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding`; you can set it if necessary as `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` in PowerShell session.

Comment: Check `[System.Console]::InputEncoding` as well.

Comment: @JosefZ Unfortunately the behavior does not change even after setting both `[System.Console]::OutputEncoding` and `[System.Console]::InputEncoding` to `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

Comment: Check `$env:PYTHONIOENCODING`; mine is `utf-8`, and no problem with running your code…

Comment: @JosefZ Indeed that alone is enough to fix it. From my original question, I mentioned reluctance to setting the python environment variable for encoding, but I'm not sure why... maybe I thought I'd have to set it to cp1252 since that is what windows often uses, and worried about the effects of that. It's been a couple years so I honestly don't remember.... Regardless, thanks for the comments and the help; using `$env:PYTHONIOENCODING` seems like a good option.

Comment: Indeed, I went and looked at my commit history from around this time, and setting that environment variable was what I settled on. I set it, call my python script, and then restore it, I guess to try to be a good citizen in case some other python script has issues when it is set.